# Magento-2 : How to set product custom price after add to cart

Tags: magento2, event-observer, quote, multicurrency

I have used **checkout_cart_product_add_after** event, for change product price.

Used observer code like below

```
$item->setCustomPrice($price);
$item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
$item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

Above code is not working while multi-currency, On cart page, if I added the product with **price 100$** it is showing **$100**.

When I am changing currency from the switcher to INR, It was showing  ₹100.

If I disabled event and add to cart same product, it's working properly in both currencies.

Comment: Hello @SureshChikani. Did you found any solution for that?

Comment: @SureshChikani any solution?

Comment: Yes I done this but I need to find out the code for it. I will post solution here one I Free.

Comment: can you share your code , i have same issue.

Comment: I posted the answer/solution in here: [https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/248518/magento-2-product-custom-price-not-change-based-with-current-currency/370491#370491](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/248518/magento-2-product-custom-price-not-change-based-with-current-currency/370491#370491)