# Multiple currency not working with custom price quote - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, quote, magento2.2.6, currency, multicurrency

I created quote with custom price from Magento admin, it works fine but it does not work multiple currency.

e.g) I created quote to customer with custom price $10 (USD currency), when customer checks it displays the amount $10 in cart page when the customer switch currency it displays $10 without currency conversion.

I have reproduced the scenario in default vanilla setup as well.

is there anyway to achieve custom price works with multiple currency?

Comment: it is a magento bug

Comment: @AmitBera thanks. do you aware any patch available for this issue? is it a known bug? if yes, please share the ticket link, I need to know the status of this bug.

Comment: @AmitBera somebody implemented it in Magento 1.X https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37827188/magento-custom-price-value-not-converting-by-changing-currency/38243913  is that correct approach to do it

Comment: @BilalUsean Did you solved this ?

Comment: @AmitBera any implementation on this i have a same issue?

Comment: @BilalUsean do you got any solution on this

Comment: @AmitBera Did you get any solution to fly? because I have a same issue,

Comment: I posted the answer/solution in here: [https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/248518/magento-2-product-custom-price-not-change-based-with-current-currency/370491#370491](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/248518/magento-2-product-custom-price-not-change-based-with-current-currency/370491#370491)

Answer (score 0):

For that, I have the same issue regarding custom price with multi-currency setup,

but not working when currency change due to custom price,

And I have added the custom price with this solution code like,

https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-set-custom-price-of-product/

But when switch the currency but price didn't update due to our custom price

So I have applied the solution For that and it's worked fine with custom price,

```
<event name="controller_action_predispatch"><observer name="force_storecode_redirect" instance="Mconnect\Csproduct\Observer\ForceStorecodeRedirectObserver"shared="false" /></event>
```

To apply this event and set the observer,

```
<?php


public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{

    if(!empty($_POST) && (count($_POST) > 0) && (isset($_POST['currency']))){
        $currentStore = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getCode();
        $baseUrl = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
        $switchCurrency = $_POST['currency'];
        $basecuurency= $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode();
        
        
        
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $priceCurrencyFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory');
        $storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
        
        $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
        $quotea = $cart->getQuote();
        $quoteId = $quotea->getId();
        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($quoteId);
    $allVisibleItems = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
    foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $getprice =$this->_helper->getpricebyprdId($item->getId()); 
        $itemAmount = $item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice();
    
        $rate = $priceCurrencyFactory->create()->load($basecuurency)->getAnyRate($switchCurrency);
        $itemAmount = $itemAmount * $rate;
        
        $item->setCustomPrice($itemAmount);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($itemAmount); 
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);  
    }$quote->save();
    }
}
```